# Is there any way to expedite a MBP 2011 discrete GPU failure

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, gpu

I have an early 2011 MBP 15" with discrete AMD GPU. This is the same model that has the free repair/warrant described here: https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

I've already had to replace the logic board twice because of graphics issues. Is there any way to expedite the failure of my current logic board to get a replacement before the free repair expires at the end of this month? It's already showing a small amount of artifacting after heavy use. I'm afraid that the Apple Geniuses won't repair unless it's a complete failure (like my previous two).

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

My reputation is too low to comment so I am writing it here.

bob gave you wrong information.

If you go to Apple's official page https://www.apple.com/sg/support/macbookpro-videoissues/
it says that

> The program covers affected MacBook Pro models until December 31, 2016 or four years from its original date of sale, whichever provides longer coverage for you.

The longer would be until 2016 December for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume the only way to expedite the failure is to run the GPU hard for a long time so that it generates a ton of heat. You could try running some of the 3D benchmarks like [Valley](https://unigine.com/products/benchmarks/valley/) in continuous mode. Turn up the features and I believe there is a "run forever" toggle (haven't looked in a long time). I think there are a few other tools like this, but that is the one that comes to mind.

Note that the warranty stops Dec 31, 2016 or 4 years from your purchase, whichever one comes first. Did you buy your laptop before Dec 31, 2012?

Comment: I unfortunately did buy it before Dec. 31, 2012. I bought it around July of 2011.